# Jupyter replaces '&' by '&amp;' in url

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, urlencode

I am trying to build url in python using urlencode with the following code:

```
url = "https://api.geoapify.com/v1/geocode/search?"
search_params = {
    'text': 'location',
    'apiKey': 'XXX'
}
print(url + urlencode(search_params))
```

Which returns: `https://api.geoapify.com/v1/geocode/search?text=location&amp;apiKey=XXX`. Somehow it replaces '&' by '& amp;'.

However, what I would expect is this: `https://api.geoapify.com/v1/geocode/search?text=location&apiKey=XXX` (which is the url that would work).

Strangely if I remove the 'http' in the url variable:
`url = "api.geoapify.com/v1/geocode/search?"` and run the same code it returns `api.geoapify.com/v1/geocode/search?text=location&apiKey=XXX`, and does not replace.

So it looks like Jupyter (I have tried outside and it is only Jupyter) recognizes that it is an url an automatically replaces special character.

Anybody have any idea how to avoid Jupyter to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Is it actually relevant for you how the url is *printed*? Jupyter should only modify how it shows the string to you, it should not actually modify what the string contains.

Comment: Jupyter definitely has no influence over how the Python code gets executed.

Comment: The way the url is printed doesn't matter indeed. But if I try to use the url `url + urlencode(search_params)` in a request(), I get an error 401. 

Now if I use the url directly as a string (with '&' and not '& amp;' in the request() it works. So it isn't just a display issue I believe...

Comment: 401 indicates an authentication issue. Are you sure the notebook has access to your credentials?

Comment: Credentials work (I have tried with just using the url and the API key). Issue that with the & amp it doesn't recognise the apiKey parameter in the url and then sends back 401.